# How to create a field with a list of instances in factory_boy

Tags: python, factory-boy

I am using factory boy to test some models (not django) and I was wondering how can I display a field containing a list with multiple instances of another factory. For example having the clases **User** and **Group**:

```py
class User:
  name = StringType(required=True)

class Group:
  name = StringType(required=True)
  user = ModelType(User)
```

I would like to display a field called **groups** within the **User** factory which contains all the groups to which such user belongs to. Showing two groups by default ['**group1**', '**group2**'] when running the factory.

```py
class UserFactory:
    name = factory.Faker('first_name')
    groups = factory.RelatedFactory(GroupFactory, 'user')

    class Meta:
        model = User


class GroupFactory:
    name = factory.Faker('word')
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
```

I have tried using a related factory as displayed above, but I don't know how to define default values for the related fields. Is there any Factory-boy guru around who can bring some light to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is mentioned in the Common recipes part of the factory boy documentation: http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#simple-many-to-many-relationship

If you create your UserFactory like in the documentation, then you can provide groups when using the UserFactory:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User

    name = "John Doe"

    @factory.post_generation
    def groups(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of groups were passed in, use them
            for group in extracted:
                self.groups.add(group)
```

You can use it like this:

```
group1 = GroupFactory()
UserFactory.create(groups=[group1,])
```

If you want to provide default groups for every user created by the factory, then you can add an else clause to the if:

```
@factory.post_generation
def groups(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
        # Simple build, do nothing.
        return

    if extracted:
        # A list of groups were passed in, use them
        for group in extracted:
            self.groups.add(group)
    else:
        self.groups.add(GroupFactory(name='default group 1'))
```

The example in the docs is using Django, so I used it in the answer as well.